How to avoid generated links to issues with hash # in gitlab wiki pages
When using the hash sign and a number in text on a gitlab wiki page the html renderer will generate a link to the issue corresponding to that number.
Example
We should start with #1

Will generate a link to issue number 1. Sometimes #1 refers to something else than an issue, how can I avoid the generated link?

"If you don’t want #123 to link to an issue, add a leading backslash \#123."

Webpage loads lazily and anchors doesn't work on Google Chrome, unfortunately. The header text is "GitLab-specific references".

Just escape the hash sign with a backslash:
Example
We should start with \#1

